# How to get power lines and substations data for Mexico

Tags: data, mexico

I am looking for an electric lines shapefile for Mexico and other Central and South American countries. Do you have any idea where I can get this data?

Comment: Good luck. In the states, this is expensive, proprietary data. I have no idea how it works it other countries, but I doubt it's free, if it's available to the general population at all.

Comment: can be purchased from http://www.platts.com/Products/gisdata/CoverageDetails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jorge;

Check out the Topographic chart 1:50,000 freely available at inegi.org.mx it has the layer of electric lines (http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/topografia/default.aspx)

Saludos
Juan José Del Toro

Comment: unfortunately the link doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will have everything you are looking for but its free. You have to create an account with them before you can download though. Additionally, Power lines in the US are at least partially represented in the CENSUS "all lines" Tiger/line shapefile. Check out this link for other countries.
http://data.geocomm.com/catalog/